# Problem when running Thunderbird from app launcher

Tags: rhel, thunderbird, gnome-panel

I'm having an issue with Thunderbird. I created a shortcut in the app launcher but when I start Thunderbird from there it doesn't download any email and the folders are empty. It works fine when launching from the terminal.

I think the problem is from where the command is executed. Thunderbird is under ~/Applications/Thunderbird and I usually cd up to its location then run thunderbird. The other day by mistake I run it from home instead of going in the folder first (i.e. ./Applications/Thunderbird/thunderbird) and got the same issue of the launcher: application unable to download any emails and empty folders.

Is there a way to set up the shortcut in the app launcher to execute thunderbird as if I were in its folder?

Comment: `cd $HOME/Applications/Thunderbird && ./thunderbird` ?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov that doesn't work: "Failed to execute child process 'cd'"

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a script and linked the launcher to it instead:

```
!#/bin/sh
cd ~/Applications/Thunderbird
thunderbird
```

I'll leave the question open in case someone can provide a better solution